# What is name of this component in Android?

Tags: android, components, material-design

I'm building a form like below. What is name of this component, and how can I make it?

Form:

[image: Form like this:]

After I click on the down arrow icon ╲╱ it's expanded:

[image]

Comment: That could be any layout hidden when you click the arrow, it just gets expanded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this can be done by using only a LinearLayout with 2 EditTexts in which you make it visible or not, programmatically.

To animate when opening, you can set this in your parent layout:

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

Arrow OnClick method example:

```
LinearLayout llExtraFields = findViewById(R.id.llExtraFields);
if (llExtraFields.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    llExtraFields.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
    llExtraFields.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: so what is happen when I click button arrow(I mean, what is content in onclick method ?)

Comment: Look the answer onclick method sample.

Comment: After that you just need to change de arrow down icon to arrow up and vice versa.

Comment: You're welcome. If it helped you, leave a vote to help others find the answer.

Comment: So can I make it appear with duration animation?